# How can I solve this Error in creating a new Django project?

Tags: django, python-3.x, windows

I was trying to create a new Django project in a new folder, located on the Desktop (Windows 7). But when I type `django-admin startproject mysite` in cmd I get this error. Can anybody help me with this?

```
C:\Users\Rovshan\Desktop\Django-examples>django-admin startproject mysite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python34\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python34\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python34\1ib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
280
  subcommands = [*get_commands(), ’help’]
                        ^
SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a unpacking problem, you can fix this by upgrading your python version to 3.5